# A good/modern template for ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm starting a new ASP.NET MVC 2 project, but unfortunately I'm a noob dev. Can you recommend a template I can use for my web site? It would be nice if the CSS supports stuff like 3 columns, 3 rows, with up, left, down and right parts being fixed size and the center auto sizing. Actually a clean CSS template would do too.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [freecsstemplates.org](http://www.freecsstemplates.org/)

They have some free CSS templates you can use to get started.

Your views in ASP.NET MVC should be primarily content and not structure. Same is true for ANY web development. As much of the structure and layout should move to CSS as possible. The reality is that you often have to compromise, but I'd start with CSS as much as possible.

Have you done much web design? If not I'd start there. Learn HTML and CSS first. Those apply whether you are doing ASP.NET MVC, Webforms, Ruby On Rails, PHP, or Perl + CGI (or just abut any other web dev) on the back end.